# Insert into table on duplicate update but keep certain columns old values

Tags: php, mysql, on-duplicate-key

I have a myIsam table `people` as follow:

`[id][name][cat]` with values: `12,"John Doe", "worker"`

`id` is unique and `name` is fulltext.

I put some values inside by a remote file call. Then I change manually `cat` value to another different value:

`[id][name][cat]` with values: `12,"John Doe", "player"`

When I update values from a remote file again to insert into table, I don't want the column 'cat' get old remote values from file in case row have same id. I just want to keep the manually entered value. But still retrieving the old value!

I am trying with this code and it's doesn't work.

```
INSERT INTO people (id,name,cat) VALUES (12,'John Doe','worker') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = '$name',cat = VALUES(cat);
```

Comment: If you do not want a value updated, don't do it in the update part, so just remove them from the update...

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Your SQL does not look correct for what your explination appears to be doing. All rows in the database must have a unique key. You only insert when no row exists with that key. If key alerady exists, you use update. What you seem to be trying is an incorrect 'upsert' type operation. Think you need to go back to basics with your SQL

Comment: Thanks @Naruto for your answer. The problem is i removed from update but still appears as updated old value.

Comment: Solved. Was a temporary and crazy failure in mysql server.

Comment: I really hope for your sake that `$name` is [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php).